# CTRL C behavior in hierarchy of shells

Tags: bash, signals, subshell

I open a shell (like `sbt` or `node debug` from my bash). Then inside this shell, I open another one (using `scala` or `node repl` respectively). Now I want to close the last shell and come back to the first one I opened (e.g. the `sbt`), but when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, all shell hierarchy is being closed and I come back to the original bash terminal.

As I learnt from [here](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html), this behavior is not standard and is undesirable for me.

**EDIT:**
I'm struggling this issue with `node debug`, so actually the issue isn't about `sbt` and `scala`.I used them to perform an experiment that shows a general nonstandard behavior of my bash. I found a similar issue with windows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793312/node-repl-exit-within-debugger-on-windows), but I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Generally when at any sort of interactive prompt from which you wish to exit, you should use CTRL + D.

Comment: CTRL + D closing the terminal completely, while I wish to come back to the first interactive prompt (e.g. sbt)

Comment: @leonprou - can you give us more details around what your're doing to launch this other "command" from within `sbt` or `node debug`? I have `sbt` installed and cannot understand what you're doing inside of it, that would require the break as you've described.

Comment: @slm in the `sbt` i type `console` to open `scala repl`, than I wish to quit `scala` and come back to `sbt`. But when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> both `scala` and `sbt` are being closed.

Comment: @leonprou - typing exit works to leave console.

Answer (score 1):

Typing the command `exit` or `quit` will exit the `console` that's been nested inside of `sbt`. You can also abbreviate these commands like so:

```
scala> :q
Not interrupting system thread Thread[process reaper,10,system]

[success] Total time: 138 s, completed May 25, 2014 1:33:22 PM
>
```

Or as `:e`. This info is covered in the help page of `console`.

```
scala> :help
All commands can be abbreviated, e.g. :he instead of :help.
Those marked with a * have more detailed help, e.g. :help imports.

:cp <path>                 add a jar or directory to the classpath
:help [command]            print this summary or command-specific help
:history [num]             show the history (optional num is commands to show)
:h? <string>               search the history
:imports [name name ...]   show import history, identifying sources of names
:implicits [-v]            show the implicits in scope
:javap <path|class>        disassemble a file or class name
:load <path>               load and interpret a Scala file
:paste                     enter paste mode: all input up to ctrl-D compiled together
:power                     enable power user mode
:quit                      exit the interpreter
:replay                    reset execution and replay all previous commands
:reset                     reset the repl to its initial state, forgetting all session entries
:sh <command line>         run a shell command (result is implicitly => List[String])
:silent                    disable/enable automatic printing of results
:type [-v] <expr>          display the type of an expression without evaluating it
:warnings                  show the suppressed warnings from the most recent line which had any

scala>
```

#### Keyboard shortcuts in console?

What you're really after here is to find out what keyboard shortcuts if any are available to you via `console`. To that end this post would seem to indicate that there are few to use:

> I found the key shourtcut in scala interpreter, only support ctl+a,ctl+e,and ctl+f,ctl+b, and even tab key  not supprt , not  to mention code autocompletion (like f#'s)

***Source:*** [Subject: scala interpreter console keyboard shortcut and
code autocompletion? - msg#00309](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.scala/2008-09/msg00309.html)

#### What about REPL?

According to this SO Q&A titled: [Is there a way to use ctrl-d as forward delete in Scala's REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384852/is-there-a-way-to-use-ctrl-d-as-forward-delete-in-scalas-repl) you can either make use of the default keybindings in Scala 2.9's REPL via the `:keybindings`.

You can also apparently override the keybindings with your own custom ones like so:

```
$ scala -Djline.keybindings=/path/to/keybindings.properties
```

See the SO Q&A referenced above for more details.

Comment: Well thanks, but my question was about more general behavior of sub-shells and not about `sbt`-`scala repl` (that was just a known example). Actually, I have difficulties with `node debug repl` sub-shell, so if anyone would figure out this specific case he'd solve my problem. Hope your answer will help some other poor folks :)

Comment: @leonprou - I didn't say this directly but the point is the keybindings aren't generic like you're thinking, they're determined by the shells themselves.  The shells being `scala's console`, `sbt`, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you type on the commandline: `kill -l`, you will see all the different interupts that exist. Not all are user-configurable.

`stty` will set your action (interrupt) with the keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>, etc)

`stty intr ^C` will set the key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> as you expect.

Another interesting feature is trapping.

If you use: `trap 'echo tried it' 2`, it will trap your interrupt and substitute it for `echo tried it`

This is a nice way to shield your shell-script from aborting to the commandline.